# Azure Deployment Source - Triggers?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, continuous-delivery

How can I tell the Deployment Source to only run when there have been changes to specific project(s)/file(s)?  In other words, something like Triggers.

I know Triggers are different, because that would be the Repo checking the file differences and kicking off a build.  Whereas Azure appears to subscribe to my Repo, and the Repo tells my Azure CD when a commit is made, so Azure pulls that solution and builds it.

On a side note: Can I have Azure decide which Configuration to build in?  Debug or Release (or otherwise)?

Comment: What kind of repository source are you trying to integrate from? What kind of Azure service type you're trying to do for CI/CD? Your question is too broad?

Comment: I'm talking about an Azure AppService (Web) which has a Setting called "Deployment Source". This tool does a PULL from a Repository (BitBucket in my case), and builds then publishes the project(s). A team can use it for Continuous Deployment or Continuous Delivery depending on how the rest of their infrastructure is set up. In Azure it's just called Settings > Publishing > Deployment Source. It's a Pull-Style publish because Azure pulls the files from remote, then builds and publishes to itself. Opposed to typical Push-Style which contain a build-script locally and eventually publishes remote.

Comment: This is not Azure-Deployment, because Azure-Deployment is a whole subset of usage where third party tools, as part or the end of their build process, push-publish to Azure.  This is also not Continuous Integration, because this isn't the act of building/testing multiple times a day (Which leads into CD).  It could be Continuous-Delivery or Continuous-Deployment, depending on how you utilize the Deployment-Source tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [custom deployment script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) to specify the configuration you want to do the deployment in.

That script will be triggered every time you make a change, but you can probably write the script in a way that lets you check to see if the files that you actually care about have been modified.

Comment: This looks very promising.  I am going to research more into it to see if I can write the script in a way that answers my question.  Thanks for the lead.